# How to make id clickable and link to another jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

Database result screenshot has been attached. Now i want to make emp_no clickable and link it to another jsp file for more details.
Need suggestions.

[image: Result screenshot]

Comment: Post your jsp so we can tell

Comment: `<a href='...>`

Comment: best practice is to use MVC where your Controller is a servlet which will redirect to the relevant View (JSP)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to use the anchor tag and link it to the appropriate controller:

Something like this:

```
<a href='employeeInfoController?id=<%=id>'><%=id></a>
```

`employeeInfoController` is your Controller Servlet or JSP that shows the details of the employee whose id is passed as a parameter. The controller can be a JSP or a serlvet.

You will need to put in all the appropriate checks to ensure the person viewing the details is authorized, etc.

---

Hope this helps!